# Editing record within a text file (java)

Tags: java

This is my exact code for editing the record in my text file.
My codes are run successfully, but the records within text file doesn't update once I clicked `btnModify`. What's wrong with my codes?
P.s: These codes are used for my awt program.

```
btnModify.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ArrayList<String> tempData = new ArrayList<>();

        String requestedID = txtID.getText().trim().toLowerCase();
        String requestedName = txtName.getText().trim();
        String requestedGender = txtGender.getText().trim();
        String requestedContactNumber = txtContactNumber.getText().trim();
        System.out.println("123");

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt")){
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(fr);

            System.out.println("123456");
            while (reader.hasNext()){
                String line = reader.nextLine();
                String lineLtrim = line.toLowerCase().replaceAll("^\\{", ""); 
                String lineRtrim = lineLtrim.replaceAll("\\}$", ""); 
                String[] data = lineRtrim.split(","); 

                System.out.println("5566");

                            if(data[0].equals(requestedID)){
        System.out.println("9999");

                 data[1] = data[1].replace(data[1], requestedName);
                 data[2] = data[2].replace(data[2], requestedGender);
                 data[3] = data[3].replace(data[3], requestedContactNumber);
                 tempData.add(data[0] + "," + data[1] + "," + data[2] + "," + data[3] );

               outStream.write("{" + txtID.getText().replace(data[0], requestedID));

               outStream.write("," + txtName.getText().replace(data[1], requestedName));
               outStream.write("," + txtGender.getText().replace(data[2], requestedGender));
               outStream.write("," + txtContactNumber.getText().replace(data[3], requestedContactNumber) + "}");
               outStream.write("\r\n");

                    outStream.close();
                    System.out.println("632");
                    System.out.println(tempData);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modify Successful!");
                }
                else {
                    tempData.add(data[0] + ":" + data[1] + ":" + data[2] + ":" + data[3]);
                    System.out.println("142");
                    System.out.println(tempData);
                }
            }
            fr.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }
});
```

This is my text file format.

```
{001,Jack,male,0123456789}
{002,Mark,male,0198765432}
```

Comment: are you writing in the file? if you wont write then could be the file gets modified.

Comment: you are replacing string read from file but you are not writing it back to file.

Comment: Thanks, will try to add on the methods to write into the file.

Comment: I edited my codes, but the records are add to the end of the text file instead of changing the specific records, what's wrong with my codes.

Comment: because you are writing to the end of the file with new values for your variables txtID, txtName etc. You are replacing the values of variables with new values, nowhere in your code, are you deleting/replacing anything already written

Comment: Hmm, my bad, because I though the "replace" command is really exactly replace the position of previous one. So how to assign the modified record to a specific line within text file?